# Convert 8bpp bitmap to 32bpp bitmap C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

Is any way to convert `8bpp bitmap` to `32bpp bitmap`, basically I want to convert monochrome `bitmap` to color `bitmap`, monochrome `bitmap` have `8bpp` I want to take it in to `32bpp bitmap`, most of the question in google is conversion from upward to downward.

Comment: You need to be a little clearer as to whether your image is 8-bit because it is a single channel of greyscale data, or 8-bit because it is an indexed (i.e. palettised) image. Also, you need to be clearer about whether the resulting image is GREY32 or GREY24 plus ALPHA8, or indeed GREY16 plus ALPHA16.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Sorry for that. Expecting output should be in RGBA 32 pix / GREY32

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Basically I have a monochrome image(Cursor) its 8bpp format  i want to convert in to 32bpp format.

Comment: So, for each 8-bit pixel `P` in the original image, you need to write four 8-bit pixels in the output image, namely `P`, `P`, `P` and `255`. That will make the Red=Green=Blue (i.e. grey) and the alpha channel fully opaque (255).

Answer (score 2):

8bpp usually indicates that you have a color map, and the pixel color value is an index into that map.

32bpp is usually RGBA or ARGB, with individual Red, Green and Blue (and Alpha) components.

To convert a indexed color-table image to an RGB image you simply replace all pixels in the 8bpp image with the corresponding RGB value from the color table.

---

In response to the comment by Mark Setchell, handling an 8-bit grayscale value is almost even simpler: Take the pixel value from the original image, and use that for all of R, G and B.

E.g. if the original pixel value is `0x37` then each of R, G and B also becomes `0x37` (i.e. `0x00373737` for ARGB and `0x37373700` for RGBA).

Comment: What you say is correct, but 8-bit could equally mean a single channel of greyscale values and that maybe seems more likely here as OP says his image is monochrome.

Comment: Im very new to the image processing concepts if any piece of code it more heplfull.

Answer (score 2):

This is some code based on Mark Setchell's comment ("*P, P, P + 255*"). 
(This is not tested, sorry - I might have some 'off-by-one' errors,  but I just want to give you an idea of what it looks like):

```
/// NB this will allocate memory, where you put the 
/// malloc depends on your context. But you do need one somewhere.
/// pImgOut is the resulting 32 bits-per-pixel image.
/// width and height are the width and height of original 8bit pixmap.
void make8bppTo32bpp(uint8_t* pPixmapIn, uint8_t** pImgOut, int width, int height)
{
     *pImgOut = (uint8_t*)malloc((width*height)*4); //32 bits per pixel == 4 bytes per pixel

     uint8_t* pSrc = pPixmapIn;
     uint8_t* pDst = *pImgOut;
     for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
         for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         {
             // assign R,G,B of dest all to be the same cur pix val of src.
             uint8_t pixval = *pSrc;
             *pDst++ = pixval; 
             *pDst++ = pixval; 
             *pDst++ = pixval; 
             *pDst++ = 255; // make alpha channel fully opaque

             // next src pixel
             pSrc++;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You can render the inner `for` loop and alpha as `*pDst++ = pixval; *pDst++ = pixval;  *pDst++ = pixval; *pDst++ =255;`

Comment: @Mark Setchell - done.